# Yii2 Framework: GridView, create new column with data from another tablet with indirect relationship

Tags: gridview, relational-database, yii2

I need your help, please.
I'm using Yii 2 Framework and i generate my models, controller and views with Gii!

I have a database with 3 tables. My database model is here:

[Database Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPRJA.png)

Now, in the Gridview of "colaborador", i want to create a new column with data from "carreira" table.
 The values must be filled this way: "colaborador" has a "categoriaprofissional" that belong to a "carreira".
 So the atribute "categoriaprofissional_fk" in the table "colaborador" permits to access to the "categoriaprofissional" which has a foreign key "carreira_fk" that access to the "carreira".

I'm in trouble to achieve the solution for this problem.

This is my index view of "colaborador":

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'numerofuncionario',
            'nome',
            //now this is the new column that i want to create
            [
                    'label' => 'Carreira',
                            'attribute' => 'categoriaprofissional_fk',
                    'value' => categoriaprofissional::get_carreira('categoriaprofissionalFk.carreira_fk'),
                    'filter'=> categoriaprofissional::get_carreiras(),
            ],
            //this is the "categoriaprofissional" related directly with "colaborador" and works perfectly! 
            [
                    'attribute' => 'categoriaprofissional_fk',
                    'value' => 'categoriaprofissionalFk.nome',
                    'filter'=> categoriaprofissional::get_nomes(),
            ],
                    [
                            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                            'template' => '{view}',
                    ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

And in the "categoriaprofissional" model i've created some functions to retrived data from "carreira":

```
public static  function  get_nomes(){
    $cat = Categoriaprofissional::find()->orderBy(['nome' => SORT_ASC])->all();
    $cat = ArrayHelper::map($cat, 'idcategoriaprofissional', 'nome');
    return $cat;
}

public static  function  get_carreira($id){
    $car = Carreira::find()->where(['idcarreira' => $id])->one();
    return $car;
}

public static  function  get_carreiras(){
    $cars = Carreira::find()->orderBy(['nome' => SORT_ASC])->all();
    $cars = ArrayHelper::map($cars, 'idcarreira', 'nome');
    return $cars;
}


/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCarreiraFk()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Carreira::className(), ['idcarreira' => 'carreira_fk']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getColaboradors()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Colaborador::className(), ['categoriaprofissional_fk' => 'idcategoriaprofissional']);
}
```

It doesn't crash but the result wasn't the expected (or what is my wish :) )

[Gridview Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CpFG.png)

The filter is populated with the correct values.
 The rows are populated with the categoriaprofissional_fk and i wish that the categoriaprofissional_fk worked as a related atribute to obain the categoriaprofissionalFk.carreira_fk (the same way that i obtain the categoriaprofissionalFk.carreira_fk in the last column (categoria profissional) to work as parameter for the categoriaprofissional::get_carreira('categoriaprofissionalFk.carreira_fk') function.

Need your help, please.
 Thank you